# Must a server sent event always be firing regardless of what page a user is on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I am pretty new to SSE so feel free to let me know if I've misunderstood the purpose and there's a much better way of implementing what I want!

I have a working SSE that, every minute, updates a user's dashboard. The code looks like this:

```
# SitesController
def dashboard
end

def regular_update
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: 'notice')
  begin
    sse.write(NoticeTask.perform) # custom code returning the JSOn 
    sleep 60
  rescue ClientDisconnected
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end

# routes
get "/dashboard(/:id)" => "sites#dashboard"
get "/site_update" => 'sites#regular_update'

# view - /dashboard
var source = new EventSource('/site_update');
source.addEventListener('notice', function(event) {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data)
  appendNoticeAndAlert(data)
});
```

This works just fine. When I'm on `/dashboard` for a user, the right info is being updated regularly by the SSE, great!

However, I notice if I'm on any random page, like just the home page, the SSE is still running in the background. Now... obviously this makes sense, since there's nothing in the code that is otherwise limiting that... but shouldn't there be??? Like shouldn't there be a way to scope the SSE in some way? Isn't it a huge waste of resources if the user is never on the `/dashboard` for the SSE to be constantly working in the background, updating the `/dashboard` page?

Again, new to SSE, if this is fundamentally wrong, please advise as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller when handling SSE you're expected to do updates in a loop,
then  `ActionController::Live::ClientDisconnected` is raised by `response.stream.write` once client is gone:

```rb
def regular_update
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  sse = SSE.new(response.stream, event: 'notice')
  loop do
    sse.write(NoticeTask.perform) # custom code returning the JSOn 
    sleep 60
  end
rescue ClientDisconnected
  logger.info "Client is gone"
ensure
  sse.close
end
```

your code disconnects the client after first update and delay, but everything appears to be working because `EventSource` automatically reconnects (thus you're getting long-polling updates).

On client `EventSource` should be `close()`d once it is not needed. Usually it is done automatically upon navigation away from page containing it, so:

1. make sure that eventsource javascript is only on the dashboard page, not in javascript bundle (or is in bundle, but only enabled on specific page)
2. if you're using turbolinks - you have to `close()` the connection manually, as a quick solution - try adding `<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">` to page header or disabling turbolinks temporarily.

Also think again whether you actually need SSE for this specific task, because for plain periodic updates you can just poll a json action from client side code, that will render the same data. This will make controller simpler, will not keep connection busy for each client, has wider server compatibility etc.

For SSE to be reasoned - at least check if something has really changed and skip message if there's nothing. Better way is to use some kind of pub-sub (like Redis' `SUBSCRIBE`/`PUBLISH`, or Postgres' `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY`) - emit events to a topic every time something that affects the dashboard changes, subscribe on SSE connect and so on (may be also throttle updates, depends on your application). Similar can be implemented with ActionCable (is a bit overkill, but can be handy, since already has pub-sub integrated)

Comment: Ok so I put a `puts ">>>>> CLIENT DISCONNECTED"` in the `rescue ClientDisconnected`, but I realize that that line somehow never fires, which is annoying. Any idea why? In any case, manual testing showed that if I just include the js separately in teh page, it's enough, I have a `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` which I believe achieves the same purpose

Comment: @james does that fire when you close browser?

Comment: To your point about needing SSE, let me know your thoughts, my notice is not as simple as it appears in the demo code above, it's a calculation that pulls info from the database, kind of like a more complicated countdown timer, that's why I felt like it was better to use SSE, keeps the logic in the backend, where it's easier to manage, than to push more info/logic into the client side

Comment: the `puts` literally never fires for anything

Comment: @james add logging to `ensure` around your task and catch other exception types, also check if the task is swallowing exceptions